# How to scraper or crawler dynamic value?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, web-crawler, casperjs, scraper

I have some question i tried scraper some data like under image.

[image]

This website is constantly changing. It seems to be getting dynamic data continually.

Of course, you can do this with a certain amount of time (for example, fetching the data once every 5 seconds)

I think a lot of resources are wasted.

We used chrome's developer tools to look at the network, but it did not change.

However, the data is still being updated.

In this case, is there a way to check the data with a few seconds interval?

Can not I continue to observe that part like observer pattern?

Comment: What is the website you are talking about?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus [this Page](https://jp.reuters.com/)

Comment: Provide exact url where this element can be found, I cannot look through the whole page to help you :)

Comment: @MarioNikolaus i apologize my foolish comment, [Please look this link](https://kr.tradingview.com/widget/forex-cross-rates/) However, this data table will only be updated when the securities market is operating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website uses websockets...

You can inspect websocket traffic if you filter for WS under your network tab in Chrome. Then select the socket connection you would like to inspect and inspect frames.

All that being said, PhantomJS has quirky support for this, so I guess your best bet it to just scrape data in some interval...

Comment: Foolish question but good answer really thank you really, and Regards